# How to allow more than 5K users to join Ejabberd MUC?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Ejabberd is the massively scalable server, here's [article](https://www.process-one.net/blog/ejabberd-massive-scalability-1node-2-million-concurrent-users/) which show Ejabber can supporting 2M+ concurrent user.

But for Multi-User Chat(MUC), Ejabber supports only 5K users(as per ejabberd module code: [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_muc_room.erl#L58)).
Ejabbered should be able to handle more user than that, so my questions to Ejabberd Gurus out there:

1. Why Ejabberd impose the limitation to only support 5k Users in MUC?
2. How to support more than 5K users in the MUC?
3. Will clustering be able to mitigate this limitation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the term "user", but obviously you are not thinking in persons, in human beings, right?

I hope you don't plan to have 5.000 human beings joining and leaving a single chatroom, sharing their presence everytime they join and leave the chatroom with the other 4.999 people. I hope you don't expect those 5.000 people sending public messages to all the other 4.999 people.

That would be a cricket cage.